# How to create a "loader file" for controllers with angularjs + requirejs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I've been trying to create an AngularJS+RequireJS project. After much pain I've managed to bootstrap the app and register controllers from a different file. I want to create a file to load all the controllers for me. I have two controllers, one of which is loaded directly and one through loader.js. The second one is not loaded (`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CtrlTwo' is not a function, got undefined`). Here are the relevant parts:
**require-config.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        angular: 'vendor/angular/angular'
    },
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    },
    deps: ['app']
});

require(['angular', 'app', 'controllers/CtrlOne', 'controllers/loader'], function(angular) {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

**app.js**

```
define("app", ['angular'], function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [] );
    return app;
});
```

**controllers/loader.js**

```
require([
        'controllers/CtrlTwo'
    ], function () {});
```

Both controllers have the same code (apart from the names and that in CtrlOne $scope.a="Hello"):
**controllers/CtrlTwo.js**

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    console.log("This code does run");
    var second_controller = angular.module('myApp').controller('CtrlTwo', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.b = "World";
    }]);
    return second_controller;
});
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="CtrlOne">
        {{ a }}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="CtrlTwo">
        {{ b }}
    </div>

    <script data-main="require-config" src="vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</body>
```

CtrlOne works fine, but CtrlTwo is not defined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loader file, you are using a `require` wrapper. As you are making a new module, you should use a `define` wrapper.

Your loader should look like:

```
define(['controllers/CtrlTwo'], function () {

});
```

The documentation has more information between the difference between the `require` and `define` wrappers: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

Answer (score 0):

inject app module to  ctrlTwo and ctrlOne

```
define(['angular', 'app'], function (angular, app) { var second_controller = app.controller('CtrlOne', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.a = "Hello";
}]);
```

}